# How to properly set up a different public folder in laravel for use with vite?

Tags: laravel, vite

I have the following folder structure:

```
/laravel
/public_html
```

If I add this to my laraval config file located at /laravel/bootstrap/app.php:

```
$app->usePublicPath(realpath(base_path('/../public_html')));
```

Then it correctly compiles the css and js files. But then when I run "npm run dev", then the hotswitching no longer works.

If I remove the above line, then it cannot compile the files correctly, and I got 404's, but then the "npm run dev" part works again.

I've got this in my vite.config.js file:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
 
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/scss/app.scss', 'resources/js/app.js'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
    build: {
        outDir: '../public_html/build',
        emptyOutDir: true,
        rollupOptions: {
            output: {
                manifest: true,
            },
        },
    },
});
```

Furthermore, I also notice that if I delete /laravel/public, then it it can't create the hot file at /laravel/public/hot. So even though I told it to use a different public folder, vite is still using the old public folder.

The issue is certainly path related, but I am out of ideas. Any suggestions?

Thanks!